# Why is the commutator group a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

I am in Intro to Algebra, and have a question regarding the commutator subgroup. I am a bit confused with the premise, though, with how the set is a subgroup in the first place.

Let $C$ be the set of commutators of $G$. Then two arbitrary elements of $C$ would be $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $cdc^{-1}d^{-1}$. I don't see how $C$ is closed under multiplication. That is, I don't see how
$$aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}\in C.$$
Am I making a wrong assumption in assuming that the binary relation is multiplication? Any help would be appreciated. Again, this is my first semester of algebra, so try to keep it basic.

Comment: The commutator subgroup is *generated* by elements of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, it's not just those elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the **set** of commutators need not be a subgroup ([take a look at this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59816/why-is-the-set-of-commutators-not-a-subgroup?rq=1)). But that's not a problem, because the commutator subgroup of a group $G$ is *defined* to be the **subgroup generated by** the set of commutators of $G$ ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup)).

Comment: Perfect; thanks a lot.