# Prove that a certain element of the commutator subgroup of $F_4$ is not a commutator

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F_4$ be the free group on the letters $a,b,c,d$.  I would like to prove that the element $[a,b][c,d] = aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}$ is not equal to $[x,y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ for any elements $x,y \in F_4$.

Comment: Note that it is sufficient to find any group in which the set of commutators is not a subgroup (since you can construct a homomorphism from $F_4$ to that group sending $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ to two commutators whose product is not a commutator).

Comment: Also it seems this has been asked several times; probably the most useful instance is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59816/197161

Comment: @stewbasic Ahh, right - thanks!!