# An undergraduate level example where the set of commutators is proper in the derived subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

The derived subgroup is the subgroup *generated by* the set of all commutators of a group $G$.

I always used to forget that "generated by" part.  Soon I will be teaching a group theory course and wish to prevent students from making the same mistake.

> Is there an easy example, presentable to beginning group theory students, of a group in which the set of commutators is proper in the derived subgroup?

I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/derived-subgroups-and-commutators) question, but the students I will be talking to will be below the level of wreath products, so the [paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2321253?uid=3739840&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101578426957) linked there isn't of any use.  Is there perhaps an example in the infinite groups which would be easier to understand?

Comment: I think this is true of the free group on two generators.

Comment: There are (many) infinite groups where this is true; proving it so is an entirely different question...

Comment: See J.J.Rotman's book of *An Introduction to the theory of groups*, page 34. I hope it helps you. Nice question.

Comment: Related - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/derived-subgroups-and-commutators

Comment: wrt anon's link, [Arturo's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/derived-subgroups-and-commutators/7819#7819) tells us that the smallest such group has order 96.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This publication *[On Commutator Groups](http://faculty.evansville.edu/rm43/publications/commutatorsurvey.pdf)*, by Kappe and Morse is great to read. Among many, it contains the following theorem: 
 If $G$ is a finite group with $|G : Z(G)|^2 < |G'|$, then there are elements in $G'$ that are not commutators. 
With the help of this one can construct a large family of groups of nilpotency class 2 with the property that the set of
commutators is not equal to the commutator subgroup.