# $D(G)$ is finite if $G$ has finitely many commutators

Tags: group-theory

I read somewhere that if a group $G$ has only finitely many commutators then the commutator subgroup $D(G)$ is itself finite.

Do you know a proof of this result?

Comment: Let me figure this out: You want to show that $D(G)$ is finite if $G$ has finitely many commutators, right? But is $D(G)$ not defined as the subgroup of commutators? Am I misreading something?

Comment: @awllower: $D(G)$ is the subgroup *generated* by the commutators. The commutators themselves do not form a subgroup in general, [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/59816/) for a discussion.

Comment: @Martin I see. Thanks for pointing out this.

Comment: [@awllower](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/262218/12952)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am sorry but I do not have a complete answer at the moment.

I will show that if $G$ is finitely generated and there are only finitely many commutators, then $D(G)$ is finite.

We will prove that the center of $G$, $Z(G)$ has finite index in $G$, then a theorem by Schur will allow us to conclude.

If $G$ is finitely generated, take $g_1,\ldots,g_n\in G$ to be a generating set. We have
$$Z(G)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n Z(g_i),$$
where $Z(g)$ is the centralizer of $g$ in $G$.

It suffices to prove that every $Z(g_i)$ has finite index in $G$; this is the same as asking to verify that every element $g_i$ has finitely many conjugates.

Take $h\in G$. We have $hgh^{-1}=g[g^{-1},h]$. Since there are only finitely many commutators, every $g\in G$ has finitely many conjugates.

Hence $Z(g_i)$ is of finite index in $G$, for every $i=1\ldots n$.

Now, we have the following theorem

**Theorem (Schur)** If $[G:Z(G)]<\infty$, then $D(G)$ is finite.

I learned about this theorem in the italian book *Gruppi* by Antonio Machì. There is now a [translated edition](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-88-470-2421-2/page/1) where it is Theorem 2.38 on page 84.

Comment: But if $G$ has only finitely many commutators $[g_i,h_i]$, then $D(G) = D(H)$ with $H = \langle g_i,h_i \rangle$ finitely generated, so the result is true for arbitrary $G$.

Comment: You are right! Thanks

Comment: I added a precise reference. Here are screen shots of the relevant passage: [part 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Br9D.png) and [part 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5xj05.png).

Comment: The same proof can be found in *Problems in Group Theory* by J. Dixon (problems 5.21 to 5.24).