# Intersection of two groups of finite index is a group of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

These questions may occur to be simple, but I can't wrap my mind around them.

1. Why the intersection of two groups of finite index is a group of finite index?
2. Why if $g\in G$ has finitely many conjugates then the centralizer $C_G(g)$ has a finite index in $G$?

I have these questions when try to understand the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285852/dg-is-finite-if-g-has-finitely-many-commutators).

Comment: It might help for you to relate the index of a subgroup with the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes obtained after quotienting the parent group by the subgroup.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass, this relation I have in mind, since this is the definition of index =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let $G$ be a group and $H, K$ be subgroups. $H, K$ have finite index iff the $G$-sets $G/H, G/K$ are finite. Now I claim that $G/(H \cap K)$ is naturally isomorphic to the orbit containing $(e, e)$ in the product $G$-set $G/H \times G/K$, which is necessarily finite (and in fact has size at most $|G/H| \times |G/K|$).
2. The conjugates of $g \in G$ are the orbit containing $g$ in the $G$-set given by $G$ itself with the conjugation action. The centralizer $C_G(g)$ is the stabilizer of $g$ with respect to this action. Hence this orbit is $G/C_G(g)$ and the index of $C_G(g)$ in $G$ is precisely the number of conjugates of $g$.

Comment: What do you mean by $G$-set?

Comment: @Glinka: I mean a set equipped with an action of $G$.

Comment: Is it possible to show it without using terminology of the group action? If it is, should ask another question for that?

Comment: @Glinka: it's going to be pretty hard to do any group theory if you don't know about group actions...

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing into this action thing. I get now what you did in (2). In (1) what action do we consider? How $G$ acts on $G/H$, $G/K$ and so on?

Comment: @Glinka: $G$ acts diagonally: if $x \in G/H, y \in G/K$, then $g(x, y) = (gx, gy)$. Using this it's not hard to compute that the stabilizer of $([e], [e])$ is $H \cap K$.