# Commutator of normal subgroups is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $A, B \triangleleft G. X = \{[a, b]|a \in A, b \in B\}$. Prove that if $|X|< \infty $, then $|[A, B]|<\infty$.

By definition $[A, B] = \langle[a, b] | a \in A, b \in B\rangle$. So we must prove that by multiplication of these finite number of elements we can't get infinite number of elements. How can we do it?

Comment: Question title and body do not match.

Comment: Do not use generator symbol arbitrarily.

Comment: @KennyLau what's the problem? As I know $[A, B]$ is called commutator of subgroups

Comment: You might like to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285852 which is a special case of your question. But if you want help then you say how far you have got and where you are stuck.