# A subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if...

Tags: group-theory

Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if and only if $\{g^{-1}h^{-1}gh|g \in G, h\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Attempt:
For the necessary condition, assume $H$ is normal in $G$. Then $g^{-1}h^{-1}g \in H$ for all $h \in H$. Then elements of the form $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$ make a subgroup of $H$ by closure.

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts and efforts towards a proof? For example, what condition are you using for normality, and can you see any relations between it and elements of this particular form?

Comment: I think you mean $\langle g^{-1}h^{-1}gh|g\in G,h\in H \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.  Then $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh=(g^{-1}h^{-1}g)h$ is the product of two elements of $H$ and thus is contained in $H$.  Therefore, the set $\{g^{-1}h^{-1}gh|g\in G, h\in H\}$ is contained in $H$.  We want to show that the subgroup generated by this set is a subgroup of $H$.  To do this, it suffices to consider the product of two elements of the form $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$, for $g\in G$ and $h\in H$: $$\begin{eqnarray*}
g_1^{-1}h_1^{-1}g_1h_1 g_2^{-1}h_2^{-1}g_2h_2&=&
(g_1^{-1}h_1^{-1}g_1)h_1 (g_2^{-1}h_2^{-1}g_2)h_2\\
\end{eqnarray*}$$
We have that $g_1^{-1}h_1^{-1}g_1$ and $g_2^{-1}h_2^{-1}g_2$ are elements of $H$ by normality, and of course $h_1$ and $h_2$ are elements of $H$, so $(g_1^{-1}h_1^{-1}g_1)h_1 (g_2^{-1}h_2^{-1}g_2)h_2\in H$.  Therefore, $\langle g^{-1}h^{-1}gh|g\in G, h\in H\rangle$ is contained in $H$, so it is a subgroup of $H$.

Conversely, if the subgroup generated by the set $\{g^{-1}h^{-1}gh|g\in G, h\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $H$, then $g^{-1}h^{-1}g\in H$ by closure for every $g\in G, h\in H$, so $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Please note that though the problem says "$\ldots \{g^{-1}h^{-1}gh|g\in G, h\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $H\ldots$", this is [false](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262218/an-undergraduate-level-example-where-the-set-of-commutators-is-proper-in-the-der) in the case that $H=G$.  What it means is the subgroup generated by that set.