# How to prove the closure of Commutator Subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I know that a commutator subgroup $C$ of a group $G$ is defined as $C=\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}|a,b\in G\}$. When I reading the textbook, it always state that $C$ is a subgroup of $G$ and only prove if it is normal.

To prove a set is a group, we need to prove is it closure, associative, have an identity element and has inverse, but when I check my textbook on how to prove $C$ is a group, it only shows identity element and inverse, although associative is too obvious, but as the closure I cannot find a way to prove that.

The question is, how to prove that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in C$ for all $a,b,h,k\in G$?

Comment: That's **not** the definition of the commutator subgroup. The commutator subgroup is defined as the subgroup generated by the commutators.

Comment: i.e. $C = \langle aba^{-1}b^{-1} \mid a,b\in G\rangle$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You mean there are some elements in $C$ cannot express in the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ right? It is just 'generated' by it but not all of them have the form?

Comment: @postmortes Sir can you expressed explicitly how $aba^{-1}cb^{-1}c^{-1}$ can be the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$? Additionally, it seems that the two elements you choose have common variable $b$, can you write how can I write the product of the two with no common variable?

Comment: @postmortes This sounds stranges, can you show me what other things I should have, to prove I can actually do that?

Comment: Actually, I've just found a simple example that shows I was wrong in my first claim, so I'm deeply sorry about that.  Consider the group $SL_2({\mathbb R})$.  $-I$ (where I is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix) belongs to the commutator subgroup but cannot be expressed as a commutator.

Comment: @postmortes Its okay... Is $I$ here a product of commutators?

Comment: No.  That's the point.  $-I$ belongs to the commutator subgroup (because the commutator subgroup of $SL_2({\mathbb R})$ is actually $SL_2({\mathbb R})$) but cannot be expressed as the product of commutators.

Comment: @postmortes How about consider $I=III^{-1}I^{-1}$? It seems like a commutator.

Comment: @kelvinhong方 But $I$ is not $-I$, so we're not talking about the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82256/discussion-between-kelvin-hong--and-postmortes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the set of commutators does not equal the commutator subgroup, as pointed out above by several remarks. See also this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/53d4/a956b11fa4a840bbac8260408cbb1c83106a.pdf) of Kappe and Morse, where criteria are discussed for equality.

I. D. MacDonald provides counterexamples in [I. D. MacDonald, [Commutators and Their Products](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323464), The American Mathematical Monthly Vol. 93, No. 6 (1986), pp. 440-444]. In particular, he proves by a simple counting argument the following theorem.

If $G$ is a finite group and $|G:Z(G)|^2<|G'|$, then $G'$ has elements which are not commutators.

Finally see also this [StackExchange entry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/derived-subgroup-where-not-every-element-is-a-commutator), which mentions another interesting paper of Marty Isaacs (also behind Jstor) with more counterexamples.