# How to solve $[a,b]\cdot[c,d] = [x,y]$ in a group $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and define the *comutator* as $[a,b] := aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ for every $a,b\in G$. About to prove that $[G,G] \leqslant_n G$, first i need to prove that is in fact a subgroup, wich is were i failed. My question is:

> Given $a,b,c,d\in G$, find $x,y\in G$ such $[a,b]\cdot[c,d] = [x,y]$.

This is for proving that $[\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,]$ are closed at $[G,G]$. The otter statments wich defines a group i've allready check it, but they doesn't defines a group if the operation $\cdot$ wouldn't give me an element of $[G,G]$. Thanks for the help.

*Mistakes.* In fact, $[G,G]$ isn't the comutator as well, so $[G,G] {\require{cancel}\cancel{\leqslant}} G$, so, the product of the comutators isn't a comutator as well

Comment: This is not the same question at all. The question in the link is about proving that it is a normal subgroup. The question here is asking help in proving something that is not true.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood exactly what the commutator subgroup is. The product of two commutators is not necessarily a commutator.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here: the product of two commutators may not be a commutator. However, the commutator subgroup is not the collection of all commutators, it is the collection of all finite products of commutators; that is, the commutator subgroup is the subgroup generated by the commutators.

Comment: Wow, so $[G,G] \neq \big\{[a,b] \mid a,b\in G\big\}$ ?

Comment: Can we define $[G,G]$ to be the smallest subgroup $H\leqslant G$ such that for every $x\in H$, exists and $n\in\Bbb N$ and $\Omega \subset \{[a,b]\mid a,b\in G\}$ such that $|\Omega| = n$ and $x = \prod\limits_{g\in \Omega} g$ ?

Comment: If I've read your comment correctly, your group $H$ will always be the trivial group

Comment: In general, $[G,G]$ need not be equal to the set of commutators; though the smallest examples are large-ish. There are several papers exploring just how large a group has to be before the set of commutators is not the commutator subgroup. Your "definition" doesn't work, but you *can* ask, for a given $G$, what is the smallest $n$ for which every element of $[G,G]$ is a product of *at most* $n$ commutators. For example, the Ore Conjecture (now a theorem) was that for a finite nonabelian simple group, $n=1$ (that is, every element is in fact a commutator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error.

In a group $G$, with $a,b\in G$, the commutator of $a$ and $b$ is $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ (note: it can also be defined as $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$; some formulas change a bit, but the basic properties are the same; the difference is that with your definition, $[a,b]$ is the unique element of $G$ such that $ab=[a,b]ba$, whereas with the other definition it is the unique element such that $ab=ba[a,b]$).

However, the **commutator subgroup** $[G,G]$ of $G$ is not the set of all commutators. It is the *subgroup generated* by all commutators. That is,
$$[G,G] = \Bigl\langle [a,b]\,\Bigm|\,a,b\in G\Bigr\rangle,$$
and not $\{[a,b]\mid a,b\in G\}$.

In fact, it is **false** that the set of commutators is a subgroup in general, though specific examples may be difficult to find, as the smallest group for which the set of commutators is not a subgroup is of order 96; this was established in Robert Guralnick's dissertation. In fact, there are two nonisomorphic groups of order 96 in which the set of commutators is not closed under products.

There is a nice note of Marty Isaacs in the Monthly providing an infinite family of examples of finite groups in which the commutator subgroup contains elements that are not commutators: [you can find it here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Isaacs77.pdf) courtesy of Pete L. Clark. It is

- *Commutators and the commutator subgroup* by I.M. Isaacs, American Mathematical Monthly **84** (no. 9) (Nov 1977), pp. 720-722

More information in [this math.overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44269/commutator-subgroup-does-not-consist-only-of-commutators/44276#44276) and [this question on this very site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/derived-subgroup-where-not-every-element-is-a-commutator)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've allready seen my mistake and put a note seeing my mistake. However, thanks a lot.