# Results that were widely believed to be false but were later shown to be true

Tags: soft-question, big-list, math-history

What are some results which were widely believed to be false, but were later to be shown to be true, or vice-versa?

Comment: What does it mean for a theorem to be "shown to be true with probability $0$"? How does one determine the "probability" of a result to be true in such a way that one can *prove* that this is the probability? Certainly one can offer heuristic arguments to *suggest* that something is "likely" or "unlikely" (or "very likely" or "very unlikely"), but these are not by way of formal proofs of the 'probability of being true'. That would require some sort of probability distribution among "statements"...

Comment: Now, if you want to ask about conjectures that were widely (and strongly) believed to be false but were later proven true (equivalently, widely believed to be true but were later proven false), then perhaps you might want to rephrase it that way.

Comment: Discussing on meta regarding reopening: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/regarding-theorems-which-were-shown-to-be-true-with-probability-zero.

Comment: I didn't really know how to phrase such a question. But Arturo Magidin's 2nd comment is what I was asking for; widely believed to be true, but proven false and vice versa.

Comment: This [thread on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468/widely-accepted-mathematical-results-that-were-later-shown-wrong) could contain some things you're after. Please do try to formulate a better and more specific version of your question along the lines that Arturo suggests then the question might be reopened.

Comment: @805801: Well, you can phrase it exactly like I did; "What are examples of results that were widely believed to be false, perhaps even argued heuristically that they 'ought' to be false or were 'likely' to be false, but were later proven to be true? Or, vice-versa, that were widely believed to be true but were later shown to be false?" You should be able to edit the question so that it says something along those lines. If you do, you might garner some votes on reopening.

Comment: See also this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples. This is related since a frequent reason for conjectures being widely believed to be true is strong numerical evidence. It's not entirely clear whether you meant something like this by "probability $0$", or also wanted to include other reasons for conjectures being widely held to be true. I'd vote to reopen if you clarify the question and it differs from that other one. @Theo: Note that your MO post asks about results widely believed to be *proved*.

Comment: @joriki: I know, but that's a minor semantic/sociological difference :)

Comment: @Theo: Well, I think there's a subtle but important difference between a conjecture that was widely believed to be proven that turned out to be false, and a conjecture that was widely believed to be true (but acknowledged to be unproven) that turned out to be false.

Comment: @Arturo: No disagreement here :) I overlooked that you wrote about conjectures while the question was about theorems. I only addressed "widely believed to be true, but proven false".

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: @805801: Note that the "vice-versa" question is really equivalent to the "direct" question. If a conjecture is widely believed to be false but is later proven true, then the *negation* of the conjecture is widely believed to be true but is later proven false. They are two sides of the same coin. The difference between your question and the MO thread is not that you are asking about "false later proven true", but rather that you are asking about **expectation** rather than a mistaken belief that the issue had already been settled.

Comment: @805: +1 for your ability to navigate through the complicated web of etiquette, and eventually pose a good question.

Comment: @Arturo: Oops, thanks for pointing this out. I must really be lacking on sleep.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the motivation behind this question is.

Comment: Also, there is a large grey area, where it's not clear to me whether the answer would satisfy your criteria. For example the Shimura-Taniyama conjecture was originally formulated in very imprecise terms, more like a heuristic, which people were extremely sceptical about. When the formulation got sharper, it seems like more mathematicians were willing to believe it.

Comment: @Alex: Or the Moonshine Conjecture, which was so "out there" when originally posed (though I don't know if it came to the status of 'expected to be true' before Borcherds proved it).

Comment: @Arturo: Why did you first point out that the "vice-versa" question is equivalent, but then edited to add it?

Comment: See the discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468 .

Comment: @Arturo: I think the Monstrous Moonshine conjecture was expected by many to be true when Frenkel, Lepowsky, and Meurman constructed an infinite dimensional graded representation of the monster with graded dimension equal to the $j$ function (around 1984).

Comment: @Scott: Thanks! Just to be clear, I was expressing my ignorance on the subject, not my skepticism of the status of the conjecture.

Comment: @joriki: I pointed out that vice-versa was logically equivalent because 805801 was identifying that as the difference between his query and that in MO (it wasn't; the difference is that the query in MO was about incorrect proofs that had been widely accepted, not about expectations). But I think "thought to be true, but a counterexample was found" than "thought to be false, but a proof was found", so just in case, I added that to the body to clarify.

Answer (score 31):

[Shing Tung Yau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shing-Tung_Yau) describes that there was a general skepticism among mathematicians about the [Calabi conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi_conjecture). He presented a proof that it was false to an informal audience which included [Eugenio Calabi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenio_Calabi). On being contacted by Calabi to write him the arguments. Yau tried to make his assertions rigorous, found a mistake in his own proof, and in trying to correct it, ended up proving it.

This is described in detail by Yau in his book *The Shape of Inner Space*

On why Yau and others were skeptical. pp. 103-104

> ... but in the early 1970s, I (among
>   many others) still needed some
>   convincing that it was more than a
>   molehill. I didn’t buy the provocative
>   statement he’d put before us. As I saw
>   it, there were a number of reasons to
>   be skeptical. For starters, people
>   were doubtful that a nontrivial
>   Ricci-flat metric—one that excludes
>   the flat torus— could exist on a
>   compact manifold without a boundary.
>   We didn’t know of a single example,
>   yet here was this guy Calabi saying it
>   was true for a large, and possibly
>   infinite, class of manifolds.

[...]

> I was also wary for some additional technical reasons. It was widely held that
>   no one could ever write down a precise solution to the Calabi conjecture, except
>   perhaps in a small number of special cases. If that supposition were correct—
>   and it was eventually proven to be so—the situation thus seemed hopeless,
>   which is another reason the whole proposition was deemed too good to be true.

On proving it. pp 106

> Calabi contacted me a few months later, asking me to write down the argument, as he was puzzled over certain aspects of it. I then set out to prove, in a
>   more rigorous way, that the conjecture was false. Upon receiving Calabi’s note,
>   I felt that the pressure was on me to back up my bold assertion. I worked very
>   hard and barely slept for two weeks, pushing myself to the brink of exhaustion.
>   Each time I thought I’d nailed the proof, my argument broke down at the last
>   second, always in an exceedingly frustrating manner. After those two weeks of
>   agony, I decided there must be something wrong with my reasoning. My only
>   recourse was to give up and try working in the opposite direction. I had concluded, in other words, that the Calabi conjecture must be right, which put me
>   in a curious position: After trying so hard to prove that the conjecture was false,
>   I then had to prove that it was true. And if the conjecture were true, all the stuff
>   that went with it—all the stuff that was supposedly too good to be true—must
>   also be true.

Answer (score 16):

This may be a bit tangential to your question, but Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem probably deserves mention here. It had been widely believed since at least the beginnings of [Hilbert's program](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/) that a [decision procedure for all mathematical questions](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CFEQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.ox.ac.uk%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Fcoursematerial%2F2010%2F993%2F28%2FB1a-lecture1.pdf&rct=j&q=hilbert%20program%20decidability&ei=5Cn8TeHMEcTmiAL_t9iMBQ&usg=AFQjCNEFNu7rS4GFCzGr1ycJKSfTmmkLAA&cad=rja) could be created. Gödel showed that this is impossible, a big surprise at the time.

Answer (score 14):

$|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}^2|$, i.e. there exists a bijection from the real line to the plane.

Also, it was believed that there don't exist wild embeddings $\mathbb{S}^2\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ until Alexander found his [horned sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horned_sphere).

Answer (score 9):

I'd think any statement classified as a "paradox" would qualify here.  The paradoxes of material implication, Russell's paradox, the Banach-Tarski paradox, the cardinality of **R** exceeding that of *N* and *Q*, [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_set_theory).

Comment: This is basically what "paradox" means: "para" is "contrary to" and "dox" is "opinion". http://etymonline.com/?term=paradox

Answer (score 4):

Complexity theory is full of such nice things. [IP=PSPACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_%28complexity%29#Proof_that_IP_.3D_PSPACE) was very surprising for its time as everyone believed IP is not as strong as PSPACE.

[Barrington's theorem](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2008/11/barringtons-theorem.html) was very surprising as it was believed branching programs would admit much stronger lower bounds.

[The Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem) of an equality regarding space complexity (NL=coNL) that was believed to be false (because of our intuition regarding time complexity, where we believe NP to be different than coNP).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answers Gadi A gave, I would mention the fact that "[PRIMES is in P](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2004/160-2/p12)": i.e., the fact that there is a polynomial-time algorithm for determining whether an integer is prime or composite.