# A number theoretic example in which both "if" and "only if" are near misses

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fake-proofs

Consider $2^n-1$. Based on checking a few small numbers for $n$ (in fact, the first ten natural numbers) we might "conclude" that "$n$ is prime if and only if $2^n-1$ is prime." However, further investigation shows that for $n=11$, $2^n-1$ is not prime. Thus our claim that "if $n$ is prime then $2^n-1$ is prime" is a near miss. However, we can prove its reverse, that "if $2^n-1$ is prime then $n$ is prime".

I am looking for some elementary number theoretic examples that both directions of our eventually fake biconditional are near misses.

Comment: $n=11$ is too low for a near miss. For really impressive near misses see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples.

Comment: @lhf I know. I had the same feeling when I read John Stillwell in his book "Elements of number theory"  mentions {$n^2+n+41$} as a near miss for generating prime numbers.

Comment: Now posted also on MO: [A conjecture in which both “if” and “only if” are near misses](https://mathoverflow.net/q/287298).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you, Martin, for adding this :)