# Existence of group $G$ with $|G|>2$ and automorphism group of odd order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In Rotman's introduction to the theory of groups, there is an exercise (7.9) where one has to prove that the following facts for a finite group $G$.

- If $G$ is abelian and $|G|>2$ then $\text{Aut}(G)$ has even order
- $\text{Aut}(G)$ is not cyclic when $G$ is not abelian
- $\text{Aut}(G)$ is never cyclic of odd order >1.

This is all fairly easy, but I was wondering if there even exists a group $G$ with $|G|>2$ which has automorphism group of odd order. Anyone has an example or reference (couldn't find it by simple internet search)?

Clearly $G$ can't be abelian, symmetric, alternating, dihedral, ... so the most obvious counterexamples don't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean "odd order" in the first bullet point?

Comment: The first bullet seems wrong. $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)\cong\mathbb{Z}_3^\times\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ has even order.

Comment: The first bullet should have "even order" indeed.

Comment: yes, I meant even. I will edit, thanks!

Comment: If anyone is interested, there are also examples of complete groups of odd order (trivial centre and no outer automorphisms), but I would need to look up the references. I think the first one was found by Rex Dark.

Comment: I would be interested!

Comment: Using GAP, I found that $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{SmallGroup}(729,n))$ has order $2187$ for $n=90,92,414$, order $6561$ for $n=41,46,50,53,173,178,181,183,184,186,211,213,215,224,232,234,361,362,363,387$, order $19683$ for $n=31,69,209,351,377,467$, and order $59049$ for $n=135$. 
$\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{SmallGroup}(3125,38))$ has order $15625$.

Comment: It seems that there is exactly $1$ group of order $p^5$ with an odd number of automorphisms for $p\equiv 5 \pmod 6$, and the order of its automorphism group is $p^6$. For $p\equiv 1 \pmod 6$, the number of such groups is $3$, and their automorphism order is $3p^6$. In either case, such groups has rank $2$. GAP easily checks this for $p=5,7,11,13$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there exists indeed one group explicitly known with odd order automorphism group, of order $5^7$ and exponent $125$. For a discussion with more references see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228689/the-parity-of-the-full-automorphism-group-order-of-finite-non-abelian-groups-of).

References: [On Minimal Orders of Groups with Odd Order Automorphism Groups](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870903454557?src=recsys&journalCode=lagb20).

Answer (score 6):

There are many examples of finite $p$-groups, $p$ a prime, whose automorphism group is a $p$-group itself. So for $p > 2$ they provide examples of the kind you are looking for.

An accessible construction is given in my paper

> A. Caranti. A simple construction for a class of $p$-groups with all of their automorphisms central. Rend. Semin. Mat. Univ. Padova **135** (2016), 251-258.

The paper can be found in the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7651).

Comment: What would be the minimal order of such a group $G$ with $p$-group automorphism group (see the reference on "minimal orders")?

Comment: They're biggish, at least $p^{10} \ge 3^{10}$. I was interested in a relatively straightforward construction, not in getting small groups. But of course your reference is very interesting!

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I see we are both racing to 50k ;-) I wouldn't mind being beaten by you on the finish line.

Comment: Well, I think your article is worth more than 50k. It is very interesting and answers the question best (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is currently known that the least nontrivial odd order automorphism group has order $3^7$. It was proved by Peter Hegarty and Desmond Machale in [Minimal odd order automorphism groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0993.pdf)

Another example is definitely not minimal, but still interesting enough to be mentioned. It is a complete group of order $3\cdot 7^{12}\cdot 19$, that was constructed by R.S. Dark in "A complete group of odd order" (here is the post, from which I found out about its existence: [Does every finite non-trivial complete group have even order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906545/does-every-finite-non-trivial-complete-group-have-even-order?noredirect=1&lq=1)). It also satisfies your condition as any complete group is isomorphic to its automorphism group and moreover it serves as a counterexample to a conjecture weaker than yours - the so-called Rose conjecture, that stated, that "all nontrivial finite complete groups have even order".

Comment: In fact the smallest nontrivial complete group of odd order has order $352947=3\times 7^6$, as stated in the Remark after the statement of the main theorem in [Complete groups of order $3p^6$](https://www.advgrouptheory.com/journal/Volumes/2/M.J.%20Curran,%20R.S.%20Dark%20-%20Complete%20groups%20of%20order%203p6.pdf). For every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$, there exists a complete group of order $3p^6$, and it occurs as the automorphism group of a group of order $3p^5$.