# Find answer of $\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{y+x}=4$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, homogeneous-equation

If I had a very shallow question, then I am sorry.
$x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ and$$\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{y+x}=4$$find $x,y,z$.

I try with AM-GM, just get$$ \frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{y+x}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$

This means that the equation must have a real solution, but can not be sure there is an integer solution.

Let: $x=ay=abz$, then the equation becomes:$$\frac{ab}{a+b}+\frac{b}{ab+1}+\frac{1}{a^2+ab}=4$$

Which makes the problem become non-homogeneous, and seems to become more difficult. I have no more ideas. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $y+z=a$ etc.  $$2(4+1+1+1)=(a+b+c)\left(\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c\right)$$

Comment: Maybe a track using $\frac{x}{y+z} = \frac{x+y+z}{y+z}-1$, I get the equation $(x+y+z)^2=7(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$. Then I suppose that $7$ divides $x+y+z$.

Comment: I wrote a small brute force program and find no solutions with $x,y,z \le 1000$

Comment: See the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences https://oeis.org/A283564, where one comment says the first solution has 81 digits.

Comment: This should help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227713/estimating-the-size-of-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation

Comment: @Mike Miller Thanks,I already known it,and you can see  the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences https://oeis.org/A283564

Answer (score 14):

There are indeed positive integer solutions. The smallest solution with $x, y, z$ in $\mathbb{N}_+$ is

$\small x = 154476802108746166441951315019919837485664325669565431700026634898253202035277999\\ 
\small y = 36875131794129999827197811565225474825492979968971970996283137471637224634055579\\
\small z = 4373612677928697257861252602371390152816537558161613618621437993378423467772036$

(Source: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y+z-+-frac-y-z+x-+-frac-z-x+y-4 )

This solution was found using elliptic curves. Quite cool, eh?

Comment: If there is a solution. Then infinitely many of them. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264754/solution-to-a-diophantine-equation/275193#275193

Answer (score 4):

Well, why not? Multiplying through by denominators leads to cubic surface
$$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3 \left(x y^2 + x^2 y + y z^2 + y^2 z + z x^2 + z^2 x \right) - 5xyz = 0  $$
which
has integer points
$$ (1,1,-1),  $$
$$  (11,4,-1), $$
$$  (11,9,-5)    $$
and perhaps no others except for permuting and changing all signs. Or multiplying by any common integer factor.

The first triple cannot be used in the original problem, the second and third work fine.

Comment: Can you say how did you find these numbers ?

Comment: OP asked for positive solutions, but it is nice to see these.  I was worried my program hadn't worked, but I required positive.