# Integer solutions to $\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{x+y}=4$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

A serious challenge:

Can someone find 3 positive whole numbers that solve this equation?
$$\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{x+y}=4$$

The numbers **must** be whole!

Comment: Do you have the answer?

Comment: what have ___you___ tried so far?

Comment: also what leads you to believe there is a solution? brute force shows no solutions for $x,y,z \le 250$

Comment: I right now have it worked down to the form ${{x^3+y^3+z^3+xyz}\over{x^2y +x^2z+2xyz+xy^2+xz^2+y^2z+yz^2}}  {+1=4}$

Comment: I know that there is a solution because I know it. The tag of the question is puzzle.

Comment: @soccerStack If you already know the answer, then this isn't the website to post a puzzle. You should post it on the puzzling SE website.

Comment: @soccerStac: Do you really have in hand a solution with integer positive numbers? Wolfram gives the solution $(x,y,z)=(11,9,-5)$ from which  there are trivially six solutions but with one of coordinates negative. Answer being sure to this, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find answer of $\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{y+x}=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192461/find-answer-of-fracxyz-fracyxz-fraczyx-4)

Comment: @DietrichBurde There is no solution there

Comment: @soccerStack There is one given in the [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227713/estimating-the-size-of-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation) which is linked at the duplicate, in the article "An Unusual Cubic Representation Problem" by Andrew Bremner. It has " truly enormous size".

Answer (score 6):

An answer has been given by Michael Stoll at [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227713/estimating-the-size-of-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation), linked at [this MSE-duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192461/find-answer-of-fracxyz-fracyxz-fraczyx-4), using the elliptic curve

$$E_n \colon y^2 = x \bigl(x^2 + (4n(n+3)-3)x + 32(n+3)\bigr)
                  =: x(x^2 + Ax + B),$$

where in our case $n=4$. Then the curve is known to have rank $1$, and thus there is a solution in positive integers of "truly enormous size", see the article "An Unusual Cubic Representation Problem" by Andrew Bremner. It is given by
$$
x = 437361267792869725786125260237139015281653755816161361862143‌​7993378423467772036;
$$

$$
 y = 368751317941299998271978115652254748254929799689719709962831‌37471637224634055579‌​; 
$$

$$
z = 154476802108746166441951315019919837485664325669565431700026‌63489825320203527799‌​9
$$ 
There are other solutions in positive integers, of course, but this is the smallest one.

Comment: Typical of the expected enormity of whole solutions, when they exist, in some elliptic curves.

Comment: Is this solution possibly a multiple of *Eric Lee*'s partly negative solution $(11,9,-5)$?