# What mathematical conjectures broke down in an unintuitive way?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, conjectures, abc-conjecture

Conjectures are often based on inference from a few cases.

A famous example is the Riemann Hypothesis which states that all zeros of the zeta function have real part 1/2. All the zeros that we've found on the zeta functions had real part 1/2.

In the same fashion, the abc conjecture has been verified for a lot of large cases.

Can you think of any conjecture true for a "large" number of cases but was still proved wrong?

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That's a very interested and connected topic. Is it possible that a conjecture has a counter-proof but that no large counter-example can be provided?