# Does the Mertens function have an infinite number of zeros?

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function

The Mertens function $M\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is defined as
$$M(N)=\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(n).$$
I have a very simple question for which I cannot seem to find a definitive answer on the web. I've also consulted several books on number theory and can't even seem to find a conjecture much less a proven result.

Question 1: Does the Mertens function $M(N)$ evaluate to zero for an infinite number of integers $N$?

I also have a second related question.

Question 2: What is the largest known integer $N$ such that $M(N)=0$?

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A002321](https://oeis.org/A002321) and references there.  According to a comment by Charles R Greathouse, all integers appear infinitely often in this sequence.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132928/sign-of-mertens-function

Comment: The Mertens function was computed at every positive integer $x \leq 10^{16}$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.08551.pdf). In this interval there are $366567325$ (integer) zeros and the largest one is $9511908657769636$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume $M(x)$ has constant sign for $x > A$. Then 
$$\frac{1}{s \zeta(s)} = \int_1^\infty M(x)x^{-s-1}dx =g(s)+ \int_A^\infty M(x)x^{-s-1}dx $$
where $g(s) = \int_1^A M(x) x^{-s-1}dx$ is entire.

Hence 
$$|\frac{1}{s \zeta(s)}-g(s)| \le\int_A^\infty |M(x)x^{-s-1}|dx =  \pm \int_A^\infty M(x)x^{-\sigma-1}dx =|\frac{1}{\sigma \zeta(\sigma)}-g(\sigma)|$$
Proving $\frac{1}{s \zeta(s)}-g(s)$ is analytic  on $\Re(s) > \sigma$ and has a singularity at $s= \sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the abscissa of convergence of the integral (*this would make the RH very easy to prove or disprove* !)

But we know $\frac{1}{s \zeta(s)}$ is analytic on $(0,\infty)$ and has a pole at $s \approx 1/2+i14.134725$

Qed.

Comment: Interesting proof. I have a further question: assuming RH and given the informations about the distributions of zeroes of $\zeta$ along the critical line provided by the Riemann-Von Mangoldt theorem, is it possible to estimate *how often* the Mertens function has to exhibit a sign change?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I would try using the explicit formulas $$ \psi(x)-x-\log 2\pi = \sum_{|Im(\rho)| < T} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}+ \mathcal{O}(x^{1/2} \log^2x/T),\qquad M(x)+2 = \sum_{|Im(\rho)| < T} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho \zeta'(\rho)}+ \mathcal{O}(x^{1/2} \log^2x/T)$$ (if the zeros are simple)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Using the density of zeros, we  can try finding a simple function $h(x)$ such that $(\psi(x)-x)h(x)$ is almost always non-negative, so that $\int_1^\infty (\psi(x)-x) h(x) x^{-s-1}dx$ has a singularity at $s =\sigma$ the abscissa of convergence of $\int_1^\infty (\psi(x)-x)  x^{-s-1}dx$