# Minimal order of a counterexample to Wall’s conjecture

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, conjectures, maximal-subgroup

There used to be once a rather well known and interesting conjecture, that was formulated by Gordon E. Wall:

> The number of maximal subgroups of a finite group $G$ does not exceed $|G|$

That conjecture appeared to be false. However, the only information about it, that I was able to find, was [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/132717/110691). It contains the statement, that the conjecture was disproven, and a link to the research in which the counterexamples were found. That link, however, seems to be already dead by the time I got there.

So, my question is, what is the minimal possible order of a counterexample to Wall’s conjecture? Or, in case, if that is unknown yet, the minimal order of a known counterexample to Wall’s conjecture?

I need this kind of information for [my collection of disproven conjectures in combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830735/407165)

Comment: Have a look at https://aimath.org/news/wallsconjecture/wall.conjecture.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a pretty good summary of what is known:
aimath.org/news/wallsconjecture/wall.conjecture.pdf