# Minimal counterexample to $\frac{p - 1}{p^2}$-conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups, conjectures

There existed once a “folklore” conjecture that stated:

> Suppose $p$ is a prime. Then any finite group $G$ with $> (1 - \frac{p-1}{p^2})|G|$ elements of order $p$ has exponent $p$

This conjecture was disproved by G.E.Wall in 1965, who constructed a group of exponent $25$, where all elements of order $25$ lie in the subgroup of index $25$.

My question is:

> What is the minimal possible size of a counterexample to this conjecture?

I am interested in it [because I collect disproven conjectures with large  minimal counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830735/407165)

Note, that $p$ in this counterexample has to be $5$ of greater, as the conjecture was proven to be true for $p = 2$ and $p = 3$ by Thomas Laffey in 1976.

Comment: What is the order of the group constructed by Wall?

Comment: Since you are interested in famous conjectures with large minimal counterexamples, I have added one at [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples/352932#352932) - in case it is interesting for you. It's about faithful representations of Lie algebras, so sort of closely related to groups via Lazard correspondence.

Comment: I checked by computer, for $p=5$, there is no example of order $p^7$ or less.

Comment: @the_fox, the counterexample constructed by Wall has order $5^{46}$ and is simultaneously a counterexample to Hughes conjecture.