# What are some examples where a sequence follows a regular pattern out to very large numbers, but not forever?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question

This question is inspired by this old paper by Euler: http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/translations/E175en.pdf.

In it, Euler considers a particular sequence, and finds that the next number in the sequence can be computed by a certain recurrence relation. He doesn't have a proof, but verifies it manually up to a a large index, and is convinced of its veracity.

Much later, it was proven that Euler's conjecture was true.

This got me thinking, have there been cases where a sequence was thought to follow some pattern for a long time, but it was eventually shown that the sequence deviates from said pattern? I am not talking about questions that are still open, only those conclusively shown to be false.

Comment: See [Examples of patterns that eventually fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111440/13130) *AND* [Conjectures that have been disproved with extremely large counterexamples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/514/13130) *AND* [Examples of eventual counterexamples](https://mathoverflow.net/q/15444/15780).

Comment: The Goodstein-sequences seem to increase forever, but actually they eventually terminate with $0$.