# The Strong Law of Small Numbers on Calculators

Tags: arithmetic, examples-counterexamples, education, calculator

This question is in the spirit of Guy's Strong Law of Small Numbers, and also the following two questions

[Examples of patterns that eventually fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111440/83875)

[Conjectures that have been disproved with extremely large counterexamples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/514/83875)

But with two extra conditions:

(1) The example should be at a primary school level (preferably restricted to the four operations of arithmetic) and,

(2) A pocket calculator could be used to convinced people of the correctness of the "fake pattern".

**Why the conditions**
I am writing something on a national maths textbook for teachers. I opened the textbook (for Year 3) and the first thing I found there was "Muliplication by $10$" asking students to use a calculoter to multiply a couple of one digit and two digits numbers by 10 and "discover" what they should do when multiply a number by 10. The purpose of the textbook was to use this obseravation to teach how to multiply a one digit number by a two or three-digit number. Meanwhile stduents **LEARN** that "**You can tell by looking**" right at the early years of their schooling.

Here is one example from Guy's The Second Strong Law of Small Numbers that I am probably going to use.

> A Niven Number has been defined as one which is divisable by the sum
> of its decimal digits, such as 21 and 133. Is $n!$ always a Niven
> number?

Of course, I am going to modify the languge of the question for my purpose (e.g., dropping the notation of the factorial), and also rewrite it in a calculator friendly way (e.g., find the reminder when $24 (=2.3.4)$ is divided by $6(=2+4)$.)

If you have an example to suggest, you do not need to concern yourself with the modifications, I find my way. Of course, you are welcome to suggest your way, in particular when it comes to the use of pocket calculators.