# Theorems only valid for huge numbers

Tags: big-numbers

I am trying to find a theorem that is valid only for very large numbers.

**Example:**

There are numbers which have more than 100 distinct factors.

Above theorem satisfies this condition, but it is a trivial one. What I would like is not a trivial one just for the purpose of being for huge numbers. I mean the huge number part should be a side effect rather than main focus.

I want to use it to show that even if you use brute force, trying up to hundred digit numbers, it may still not be successful proof.

Thank you

Comment: The asymptotically-fastest known algirithm for integer multiplication is only faster than other methods when the numbers to be multiplied are larger than around $10^{10^{10^{38}}}$. Similar examples are given at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_algorithm

Comment: This is, in some sense, the same as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples)

Comment: My favourite would be : There are positive integers $x$ with $\pi(x)>li(x)$

Comment: Also related: [Examples of patterns that eventually fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111440/examples-of-patterns-that-eventually-fail)

Comment: This one is from Math Overflow: [Examples of patterns that eventually fail](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples)

Comment: @xycf7 Are the linked posts close enough to what you wanted?  If you're looking for something different, could you please amend your question to explain in what way it should be different?

Comment: @MJD they are indeed good examples. Unfortunately no one entered them as answers, so I cannot accept them. Thank you all for the information.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad we could help.  I've suggested that we close your question as being a duplicate of one of the earlier ones.