# Conjectures with the strongest numerical evidence later proven to be false

Tags: soft-question, conjectures

For a number of conjectures in number theory, the truth of some statement has been checked up to extremely large values. E.g. There are no odd perfect numbers below $10^{1500}$

Are there any examples where a conjecture eas believed to be true, and also had huge empirical evidence that it should be true, but was later proven to be false?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples

Comment: Thanks, I'll close the question